# modules over infinite fields (and rings?): does every nonzero element have infinite order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

on p359 of dummit/foote (intro paragraph to tensor products of modules), it says

> every nonzero element in a vector space over $Q$ has infinite (additive) order

i'm not sure why this is obvious?

Comment: Every nonzero integer is invertible in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: If we ever had $v + \cdots + v = nv = 0$ for some $n \in \{1, 2, \cdots\}$, then multiplying by $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ gives $v = 0$.

Comment: Since every ring is a module over itself, this is obviously not true in general. It holds over fields of characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the comments of Lord Shark and Joppy:  if $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ and

$v \in V \tag 1$

has finite additive order $n$, so that $n$ $v$s added together yield $0$,

$\displaystyle \sum_1^n v = 0, \tag 2$

then

$nv = \displaystyle \sum_1^n v = 0; \tag 3$

now since

$n^{-1} \in \Bbb Q, \tag 4$

we have

$v = 1v = (n^{-1}n)v$
$= n^{-1}(nv) = n^{-1}(0) = 0; \tag 5$

thus if

$v \ne 0, \tag 6$

the additive order of $v$ cannot be finite.